# Kendo grid prevent columns from being smaller

Tags: java, jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The grid has about 25 columns, and Kendo grid tries to fit all columns in one page horizontally, making the column names show as "...".

I'd like to show all column names by default and have a horizontal scrollbar enabled.

How can I achieve this with JSP wrapper?

```
<kendo:grid name="SRCHGT" resizable="true" sortable="true" height="500">
    <kendo:grid-scrollable virtual="true"/>
    <kendo:dataSource>
        <kendo:dataSource-transport>
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="api/products"
                contentType="application/json" type="GET"></kendo:dataSource-transport-read>
        </kendo:dataSource-transport>
        <kendo:dataSource-schema data="Data" total="Total" groups="data">

        </kendo:dataSource-schema>
    </kendo:dataSource>

</kendo:grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the width setting of the columns in order to do that. Here is a demo showing horizontal scrolling: http://demos.kendoui.com/beta/web/grid/virtualization-remote-data.html

If you want all the columns the have the same width you can also use CSS:

```
#SRCHGT col {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/edinix/1/edit

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the prompt response. There are many columns so I'd have to copy and paste a lot of column definition with pixels defined in them. I was wondering if there's a simpler way to just set all columns so that they don't shrink.